# Order of domino tiles function

Tags: functional-programming, python

The domino tiles can be listed in an orderly way as shown in the figure :

[image]

[figure link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8VUj.jpg)

**Write a function** such that given two variables ("minor" and "major") where "minor" is the  lowest value and "major" the highest value of a domino tile, **calculate its order number associated with the previous figure.**

**Example** : given a domino tile with numbers 1 and 5, the function must calculate the order number 11. Given a tile with numbers 4 and 6 the function must calculate the order number 24

---

From  the domino tile with numbers (0,0) to (1,6) the function "6 * minor + major" works but  from the next domino tile, the function begins to fail and I can't find a better function. Can someone help me please?

Comment: This is really a math rather than computer science question. I suggest spending some more time, for example figuring out what happens when minor=2 and trying to generalize. Note also that in this case you can just precompute the answer and use a lookup table.

Comment: The lookup table is probably not worth it given that you can find a simple closed formula (for the generalised set of dominos with up to $n$ dots, even).